# Call a value from an OnClick method

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working on eclipse (android) and I want to call outside a variable that is in the `OnClick` method. How can I do that? I thought to use a return but `OnClick` is a void method. Here is my code

```
 backgroundE2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View view){
         int randomIntE = random2.nextInt(Deck.length());
         int drawableIDE = Deck.getResourceId(randomIntE, -1);
         backgroundE2.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDE);
     }
 });
```

I'm trying to call the variable `randomIntE`. How can I do that if everything is closed? I have to call also other 4 variables that are in different `setOnClickListener`.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, although whatever I understand of it, you must use global variables.

Comment: Yeah but I need the value of randomIntE when it is changed so when I click the button. How can I call that particular value?

Comment: Declare it global -- update its value in the onCLick -- fetch the updated value? You can access a global variable from anywhere in the class or outside depending on the visibility. The only thing you have to make sure of is that button is clicked.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Global variable, return the variable inside the OnClick? I don't think so or I don't understand your structure

Comment: It will not access it  from within the onCLick, once you update the value in the onClick you can fetch the value after this operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable declared outside the function.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int fnsetFlag= 0;
    backgroundE2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            fnsetFlag= 1;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: answers with piece of code should not writen as a comment. The above is right and will work.

Comment: And I need value 1 for example. How can I have it back?

Comment: if the button is clicked, the variable fnsetFlag has the value 1, else it has the value 0

Comment: Ok, that's look like good. The only thing is that now I have to call fnsetFlag. I can call it outside and the value should be updated if the button is pressed. Do I understand?

Comment: yes I think you understand what I am trying to say.. try it out.

Answer (score 0):

you should save it somewhere, like in an instance variable or in an object that can be called from the piece of code you want to use.
I hope to have understand the question properly.

Andrea.